# Android app crashes need help interpreting crash log

Tags: android

I am trying to create an AlarmClock app, however, I have run into an issue. The issue occurs when I click on a certain button (Add Alarm). The button does the following:

```
public void addAlarm_Click(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_addalarm, null);

    final TimePicker MyTimePicker = (TimePicker) myView.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    MyTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    myBuilder.setView(myView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = myBuilder.create();

    Button btnAdd = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_AddAlarm_Btn_Add);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int h = MyTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
            int m = MyTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + Integer.toString(h) + " " + Integer.toString(m),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button btnCancel = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_AddAlarm_Btn_Cancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is my **dialog_addalarm.xml**:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Layout_MainHolder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout_NameHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView_Name"
            android:labelFor="@+id/EditText_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/alarm_name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:headerBackground="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:numbersSelectorColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/daypicker_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/daypicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/daypicker" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout_ButtonHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_AddAlarm_Btn_Cancel"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_AddAlarm_Btn_Add"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alarmclock, PID: 31230
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:882)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:523)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:368)
    at com.example.persson.peter.alarmclock.MainActivity.addAlarm_Click(MainActivity.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19959) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5596) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
09-12 11:25:33.774 31230-31230/com.example.alarmclock I/Process: Sending
```

I made a few changes, when it suddenly started behaving like this (crashing when I click the add alarm button.) I don't know which of the changes actually causes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is pretty self explanatory.

```
You must specifiy a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />
```

The qualifier you want is `layout=""` *not* `android:layout="`.

See here for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution:

Instead of **android:layout** use **layout:**

```
 <include
  android:id="@+id/daypicker"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout="@layout/daypicker" /> // check this line
```

Answer (score 0):

set view before the dialog show event.

```
 myBuilder.setView(myView);
 dialog.show();
```

Code interpretation and debugging code are necessary here.